# DataTables Reloads unsuccessful

Tags: jquery, api, datatables, reload

I am using the following CDN version of Datatables (*https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js*)
Which gets loaded at the page bottom likeso:

```
<script type="application/javascript"
            src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            // On page load: datatable
            var plugins_table=$('.plugins_table').DataTable({
                "ajax":"indexAjax.php?p=listPluginsforSite",
                "columns":[
                    {"data":"plugin_name"},
                    {"data":"plugin_site_version"},
                    {"data":"plugin_uptodate_status"},
                    {"data":"plugin_activate_choice"},
                    {"data":"plugin_install_choice"}
                ],
                "language": {
                processing: "Traitement en cours...",
                search: "Rechercher&nbsp;:",
                lengthMenu: "Afficher _MENU_ Plugins",
                info: "Affichage du Plugin _START_ &agrave; _END_ sur _TOTAL_ ",
                infoEmpty: "Affichage du Plugin 0 &agrave; 0 sur 0 ",
                infoFiltered: "(filtr&eacute; sur _MAX_ Plugins au total)",
                infoPostFix: "",
                loadingRecords: "Chargement en cours...",
                zeroRecords: "Aucun Plugins &agrave; afficher",
                emptyTable: "Aucune donnée disponible dans le tableau",
                paginate: {
                    first: "Premier",
                    previous: " Pr&eacute;c&eacute;dent",
                    next: "Suivant  ",
                    last: "Dernier"
                },
                aria: {
                    sortAscending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre croissant",
                    sortDescending: ": activer pour trier la colonne par ordre décroissant"
                }
            },
                paging: true,
                autoWidth: false,
                responsive: true,
                pagingType: "full_numbers",
            });
        // This event is triggered by a button with class '.activate_state' on each row...
        $('#plugins_table tbody').on('click', '.activate_choice', function () {
            var plugin_id=$(this).data("id") ;
            var plugin_active_state=$(this).data("active-state");
            var request   = $.ajax({
                url:          'indexAjax.php?p=togglePluginActiveState',
                data:         {plugin_id:plugin_id,active_state:plugin_active_state},
                dataType:     'json',
                type:         'post'
            });
            request.done(function(response){
            if (response.result == 'success') {
                // Reload datable: NEITHER commented solutions work !
                //plugins_table.api().ajax.reload();
                //plugins_table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
            }
        });
        });
        });
    </script>
```

When I do a 'manual' reload / refresh of the page, the table / page refeshes with the correct data / changes , but I can't get the API to reload the table aftre the successful ajax call...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first line you are using `api()`, but this is only needed if you initialise your datatable using the `.dataTable()` syntax (notice the small 'd'). Because you are using the `.DataTable` syntax (with capital 'D') you are already using the DataTables api.

In the second line you are trying to reinitialise your datatable, but `plugins_table` already exists as a datatable. Instead, refresh it like this:

```js
plugins_table.ajax.reload();
```

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, re-naming the datatable as per the below worked for me :

```
$('.plugins_table').DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Instead of the previous:

```
plugins_table.DataTable().ajax.reload();
```

Where '*plugins_table*' was the initial named  variable for the table.

I'd be interested in an explanation of this 'behaviour... !

Comment: Woah this sintax issue is really misleading..!<br/>
Many thanks this solved the issue